# where is the fatal error "Cannot access empty property" in the PHP class function?

Tags: php, class, function

What is wrong with this code?

```
<?php

class users {

  var $user_id,
      $f_name,
      $l_name,
      $db_host,
      $db_user,
      $db_name,
      $db_table;

  function users() {
      $this->$db_host = 'localhost';
      $this->$db_user = 'root';
      $this->$db_name = 'input_oop';
      $this->$db_table = 'users';
  }

  function userInput($f_name, $l_name) {
      $dbc = mysql_connect($this->db_host , $this->db_user, "") or die ("Cannot connect to database : " .mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db($this->db_name) or die (mysql_error());
      $query = "insert into $this->db_table values (NULL, \"$f_name\", \"$l_name\")";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if(!$result) die (mysql_error());

      $this->userID = mysql_insert_id();

      mysql_close($dbc);

      $this->first_name = $f_name;
      $this->last_name = $l_name;
  }

  function userUpdate($new_f_name, $new_l_name) {
      $dbc = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, "") or die (mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db($this->db_name) or die (mysql_error());

      $query = "UPDATE $this->db_table set  = \"$new_f_name\" , \"$new_l_name\" WHERE user_id = \"$this->user_id\"";
      $result = mysql_query($query);

      $this->f_name = $new_f_name;
      $this->l_name = $new_l_name;
      $this->user_id = $user_id;

      mysql_close($dbc);
  }

  function userDelete() {
      $dbc = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, "") or die (mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db($this->db_name) or die (mysql_error());

      $query = "DELETE FROM $this->db_table WHERE $user_id = \"$this->user_id\"";

      mysql_close($dbc);
  } 
}
?>
```

**The error is:**

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\jordan_pagaduan\class.php on line 15.

Comment: To use code format, indent the source code by 4 spaces. Don't abuse HTML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To access a [class-property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) from inside a method of a class, you must use `$this->propertyName`, and not `$this->$propertyName`.

Which means your `user_input()` method should be written like this :

```
function user_input() {
    $this->db_host = 'localhost';
    $this->db_user = 'root';
    $this->db_name = 'input_oop';
    $this->db_table = 'users';
}
```

*(you might have to do the same modification to other places)*

With what you have written, `$this->db_user` is never set ; and, later, when using this :

```
$dbc = mysql_connect($this->db_host , $this->db_user, "")
```

`$this->db_user` is null ; which means [`mysql_connect`](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect) will use the [default value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-user) -- which, in your case, appears to be `ODBC`, judging from the error message.

*(same thing with the other properties -- but I took this one as an example, as the `ODBC` default-value was present in the error message you posted : it was the most obvious choice.)*