# PHP scandir doesn't work

Tags: php, joomla, scandir

I have seen another question with the same problem, but with just 1 answer, which didn't worked for me.

The question: [PHP scandir - multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226060/php-scandir-multiple-directories/38508317#38508317)

I'm using Joomla! to create my site
(I create everything with templates, most that I don't understand creating an extension).

So, I created folder `pbfData` in main folder.
In it I created folder `users`. But scandir does not detects any of those.

Errors (without `if (is_dir)`)

```
Warning: scandir(/pbfData/) [function.scandir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in [...]/pbf/index.php on line 61

Warning: scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such file or directory in [...]/pbf/index.php on line 61

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in [...]/pbf/index.php on line 61
```

The code looks like this:

```
class users {

  var $users;

  function refUsers() {
    $dir = '/pbfData/';
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
      $this->$users = scandir($dir);
    } else {
      echo "<b>CRITICAL ERROR: </b>No access to users directory.";
    }
  }
[...] }
```

It outputs 
`CRITICAL ERROR: No access to users directory.`

(**Note:** adding `is_dir` to solve it was answer to the other question, but as I have written it doesn't work for me.)

Comment: You're setting `$dir = '/pbfData/'` and then checking `is_dir($directory)` and then doing `scandir($dir)` so if `$directory` is a valid directory you're reading from `$dir` which may not be a valid directory.

Comment: Can you link the answer that didn't work and explain why?

Comment: @apokryfos I didnt saw, but even without the is_dir checking it didn't worked.

Comment: Well based on your code, I'm going to assume that "/pbfData/" isn't a directory. It's also an absolute path which looks odd. Perhaps you meant to do something like `__DIR__."/pbfData/"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_dir` is not a solution to get directory path, it just checks if the file is a directory or not. To get the path you can use JPATH_SITE or JPATH_BASE etc as you are inside Joomla. Joomla already comes with built in constants. have a look here https://docs.joomla.org/Constants .

Your code will be

```
$dir = JPATH_BASE."/pbfData",
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! But there is still the Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in [...]/pbf/index.php on line 61. I'm not sure what does that means, but I'm going to search for it...

Comment: @Soaku If you can create a different question and post your code. I may be able to help you. You can check this links 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715610/where-is-the-fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property-in-the-php-class-functio and 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437751/cannot-access-empty-property-in-php . This may help you.

Comment: oh... Now I see what I have done wrong... I can't believe that I written `$this->$users` instead of `$this->users`

Comment: @Soaku Yes that was the mistake. minor but fatal.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the folder `/pdfData/` exists, and since the path starts with `/` what you are really checking is if you have a folder with the name `pdfData` inside your ROOT folder (`C:\` or `D:\` [etc] in windows, and `/` in linux/unix).

That means that if you run your script `/var/www/html/pdf/index.php`, event if you have the folder `/var/www/html/pdf/pdfData` - the function `is_dir('/pdfData/')` will return false, because you don't have that folder in your ROOT/

```
Folder structure
----------------
/pdfData/ <-- This is the folder that your code check (which doesn't exists)
/var/
/var/www/
/var/www/pdf/
/var/www/pdf/pdfData/ <-- This is the folder you want to check for
```

If you want to check the folder `pdfData` inside the current folder that you are running your code from, you should use `$dir = 'pbfData/';` (without the starting slash)

Another options is to use the `__DIR__` Magic constant:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . '/pbfData/';
```